# How to store variable within javascript to limit number of http calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a second party file downloader which returns a progress event.  I can capture the event and call a program on the server to perform an update (for security purposes so I can tell the most recent activity).

I get about 30 events per second all at percent downloaded 1%, then 30 more at 2%, then 30 more at 3%, etc.  I would like to limit my http calls to only once per percentage change, 1%, 2%, 3%, etc.  I would put a hidden field on the page and compare that and update it, but I cannot refresh the page since the download is in progress.

Is there a way to use some type of client side storage within javascript or jquery for this?

In other words, I need to be able to tell when the PercentCurrent value changes from 1 to 2, etc.

My javascript function looks like this:

```
         function onProgress(PercentTotal, PercentCurrent, Index){
            var xmlhttp;

            //The handler will update the file progress
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') { 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            } 
            if (!xmlhttp) { 
                throw "Browser doesn't support XMLHttpRequest."; 
            } 
            var data = ""; 
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "UpdateProgress.aspx?PercentCurrent=" + PercentCurrent, true); 
            //Send the proper header information along with the request 
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length); 
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
            xmlhttp.send(data);
        }
```

Thank you,
 Jim

Comment: how and where do you call this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does indeed have variables, you just need to store one in a *scope* that's accessible to your `onProgress` code. You may just be able to use a `var` in the same place `onProgress` is declared, but a simple and JavaScripty way to make that variable "private" is to use a closure:

```
var onProgress = (function(){
    var lastSend = 0;

    return function(PercentTotal, PercentCurrent, Index){
        if (Math.floor(PercentCurrent) > lastSend) {
            lastSend = PercentCurrent;
            var xmlhttp…
        }
    }
})();
```

This'll look a little confusing if you haven't worked with JavaScript much. Here's what's going on:

1. I create a variable called `onProgress`
2. I create and immediately run an anonymous (unnamed) function, like this: `(function(){ … })()`
3. This function defines a local variable, `lastSend`, and returns the real `onProgress` function.

Whenever a function is called in JavaScript, it has access to the scope in which it was created. So, whenever `onProgress()` is called, it'll have access to the `lastSend` variable, and can check that progress is has moved past the next whole percent.

Of course, this is a bit ugly, and it can only be used once on a page (since there's only one closure with one `lastSend` variable. Instead of assigning it to a name, you might pass it directly into the function which calls it, anonymously (see below). Then, a new copy of the function, with a new closure, gets created when you hit downloadFile.

---

Your original question is tagged [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery). If you are indeed using jQuery on the page, you can simplify the posting of data significantly (down to one line) and make it more compatible, with [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("UpdateProgress.aspx", { PercentCurrent: PercentCurrent });
```

(This would replace all the XMLHTTPRequest-related code in `onProgress`.)

---

So, using a closure and `jQuery.post` might look like this:

```
// Not sure what your second-party file downloader looks like
fileDownloader.downloadFile((function(){
    var lastSend = 0;
    return function(PercentTotal, PercentCurrent, Index){
        if (Math.floor(PercentCurrent) > lastSend) {
            lastSend = PercentCurrent;
            $.post("UpdateProgress.aspx", { PercentCurrent: PercentCurrent });
        }
    }
})());
```

Comment: This jQuery looks nice and it sure simlifies my previous code.  Thank you.  I have three great answers!

Comment: I used this, this uses the same type logic that Gotch4 supplied and additionally cleans up my http calls.   Thank you all for your answers as they were all useful information.  Jim

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery's `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). It allows you to store data and attach it to a particular DOM element like so:

```
$('body').data('foo', 52);
$('body').data('foo'); // 52
```

Comment: You're using `data` as a fancy variable… which is huge overkill for this situation. jQuery `data` is tremendously useful when you want to associate information with a particular element.

Comment: He's using jQuery, and it's safer to use than a global variable and a bit easier than writing namespaced Javascript. Further, it allowed me to make the fewest assumptions as to how the rest of the asker's code functioned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your problem. Is the page continously reloaded? If it is not all that you need to do is:

```
var lastPercent = null; // you need to initialize this when it all starts again.
 function onProgress(PercentTotal, PercentCurrent, Index){
            var xmlhttp;

if (lastPercent == PercentCurrent)
return; //Does nothing if no change occurred.

lastPercent = PercentCurrent;

            //The handler will update the file progress
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') { 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            } 
            if (!xmlhttp) { 
                throw "Browser doesn't support XMLHttpRequest."; 
            } 
            var data = ""; 
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "UpdateProgress.aspx?PercentCurrent=" + PercentCurrent, true); 
            //Send the proper header information along with the request 
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length); 
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
            xmlhttp.send(data);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you gotch... I will try that also.  That looks like it would work since the page is not reloaded.